# Can the base damage of a Sorcerous Fetish be raised?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse, minds-eye-theatre

In the new MET Werewolf book, one of the options for a Fetish is the Sorcerous cantrip, which inflicts a damage of one. Is there any way to raise that damage with Fetish or Equipment Qualities?

Comment: which book exactly?